# Certbot throws TypeError

Tags: python-2.7, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm a little stumped here. I've never seen an error from `inspect.py` before, but here I am trying to install some SSL certificates with certbot and an error occurs. The certbot log including the stack trace is [here](https://gist.github.com/jamiecounsell/a717000c27b7a598e5d5d201ad6b34ad), but the error is:

```
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/inspect.py", line 815, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func)) 
TypeError: <method-wrapper '__ne__' of type object at 0x1eeab80> is not a Python function
```

And occurs when running `certbot certonly`. Other commands, such as retrieving the version, are fine.

I've tried a few things (uninstalling/reinstalling, etc) but to no avail. I'm trying to avoid installing from git or some other source (trying to stick with `yum`). Some more details

- Centos @ 7.1.1503 (Core)
- certbot @ 0.8.1

What's strange is this error seems to indicate an error in implementation, but I find this strange, since I'm using certbot on another CentOS 7 machine without issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I will open an issue on GitHub if appropriate, but figured I would ask here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need update cryptography with:
pip2 install -U cryptography

and maybe pyOpenSSL:
pip2 install -U pyOpenSSL

You can use one command to check all requirements:
pip2 install -U certbot

Comment: I will try this! Thank you.